# How to access the value of one attribute of one table from another table (One-to-One bi-directional relationship) in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I have two classes (`application` and `employee`), which relate with a `One-to-One` directional relationship.

In my `application` class I have four attributes:

- `id_application`
- `name_app`
- `responsible_app`
- `responsible_app_backup_1`
- `responsible_app_backup_2`
- `employee_id`

In my `employee` table I have three attributes:

- `id_employee`
- `uid_employee`
- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `application_id`

**Employee:**

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Application", mappedBy="employee", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
private $application;
```

**Application:**

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="application", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
@Groups("gdc_group_application")
private $employee;
```

How can I list out `uid_employee`, `first_name`, and `last_name` to each `responsible_app`, `responsible_app_backup_1`, `responsible_app_backup_2`?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: According to your question these two entities have a OneToOne relationship, and such a relationship needs a foreign key. but none of those 7 fields (4 from application and 3 from employee) are in common. how do you say that they are in relation? where do you see the relation? I see no relation between these two tables

Comment: Please remove your comment, edit your question and add the required information into your question. keep in mind that asking a well formed question is not so easy. Put some time and effort for it

Comment: from your question is totally unclear what kind of data do you have in `responsible_app`, `responsible_app_backup_1`, `responsible_app_backup_2` fields. can you shed some light on this? maybe you can show full code of both entities?

Answer (score 0):

You're title says that you're using symfony 4. Thus, you're not supposed to consider your entities as table and columns, but as classes and attributes.

I suggest you to read the following articles:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html to understand more the ORM philosophy
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html to see how to implement associations between models.

Also keep in mind that two entities with one-to-one relation are subject to a fusion into a single entity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your info. If you understand my question, do you have any suggestion or solution?